# Compilation of nginx fails due to struct 'crypt_data' has no member named 'current_salt'

Tags: c, linux, nginx, glibc

I am trying to compile nginx on Ubuntu machine with GCC. My Glibc version is 2.31.

```
m@feynman:~/Junk/nginx-1.9.9
$ /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 --version
GNU C Library (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.31-0ubuntu9.2) stable release version 2.31.
```

I have downloaded a bunch of different versions from https://nginx.org/download/ and tried with them and fails every time.

```
./configure --with-threads --with-http_ssl_module --with-cc-opt="-Wno-error"
make
```

./configure generates following file in `objs/Makefile`:

```
CC =    cc
CFLAGS =  -pipe  -O -W -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wno-unused -Werror -g -Wno-error
CPP =   cc -E
LINK =  $(CC)

...
```

This gives me this error below.

```
cc -c -pipe  -O -W -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wno-unused -Werror -g -Wno-error -I src/core -I src/event -I src/event/modules -I src/os/unix -I objs \
    -o objs/src/os/unix/ngx_posix_init.o \
    src/os/unix/ngx_posix_init.c
cc -c -pipe  -O -W -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wno-unused -Werror -g -Wno-error -I src/core -I src/event -I src/event/modules -I src/os/unix -I objs \
    -o objs/src/os/unix/ngx_user.o \
    src/os/unix/ngx_user.c
src/os/unix/ngx_user.c: In function ‘ngx_libc_crypt’:
src/os/unix/ngx_user.c:36:7: error: ‘struct crypt_data’ has no member named ‘current_salt’
   36 |     cd.current_salt[0] = ~salt[0];
      |       ^
make[1]: *** [objs/Makefile:749: objs/src/os/unix/ngx_user.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/m/Junk/nginx-1.9.9'
make: *** [Makefile:8: build] Error 2
```

I tried installing SSL lib and others like that and thought it would help and nothing worked.

```
sudo apt install libpcre3-dev libssl-dev
```

Comment: ?Why a five year old version? `$ apt install nginx` will install version 1.18.0, which is a version for a contemporary OS.

Comment: I know. This was something in specs and will be used in a very specific environment.

Comment: »» ngx_user.c, line 36:  `´struct crypt_data’ has no member named ‘current_salt’` «« : I guess you will have to edit the C code. Other "nginx 2015 versions" have the same error with modern OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone was looking for a *solution* to the problem itself:

The field `current_salt` is no longer the name of the field where the result is stored and needs to be updated.

Instead, the field name is `output`, as defined in `/usr/include/crypt.h` on such a system:

```
/* Memory area used by crypt_r.  */
struct crypt_data
{
  /* crypt_r writes the hashed password to this field of its 'data'
     argument.  crypt_rn and crypt_ra do the same, treating the
     untyped data area they are supplied with as this struct.  */
  char output[CRYPT_OUTPUT_SIZE];
```